# ros-jade-graph-msgs missing in jade?

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the graph_msgs package was removed from ROS Jade.

The package was previously called "ros-indigo-graph-msgs"

Was it renamed or replaced with some other package?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210004/ros-jade-graph-msgs-missing-in-jade?/) by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the author just hasn't released the package for Jade yet. So far, only 520 packages have been released for Jade, so there are quite a few to come, I'm sure.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-05-27**:
But you could always just clone the indigo branch of the [repo](https://github.com/davetcoleman/graph_msgs) and build it under Jade yourself for now.

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2015-05-27**:
Thanks Tom!